# Power Apps: Comparison between TODAY() and a SharePoint date column not working

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

The following code checks if a record that matches in-app values and today's date exists on the SP list:

```
ClearCollect(
    colContextShift,
    ShowColumns(
        Filter(
            Filter(
                Filter(
                    shift_data,
                    production_line = ProductionLineCombo.Selected.Value
                ),
                shift_number = ShiftCombo.Selected.Value
            ),
            shift_dt = Today()
        ),
        "ID"
    )
);
```

On SP, I have a date type column that records as default value today's date (no time included).

The problem is that the code is not matching the output of TODAY() with the date value in the column even though the value exists. As a result, the output collection is empty. I am certain the issue is with the date portion because if I remove this component the code works fine and returns a filtered array (although, of course, not correct since the date value is being ignored during this test).

Again, the SP column is a date format column, with only date (no time included). Not sure how this would affect, but I have also made sure that the SP time zone is set correctly and is the same to the Power Apps time zone.

*** Edit
If I replace `shift_dt = TODAY()` with `IsToday(shift_dt)`, the code performs correctly and I get a properly filtered table. However, IsToday() throws a delegation warning.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the solution consisted in creating a collection using functions that delegate, and then filtering that collection using functions that would throw delegation warnings.

```
ClearCollect(
    colContextShift,
    ShowColumns(
            Filter(
                Filter(
                    shift_data,
                    production_line = ProductionLineCombo.Selected.Value
                ),
                shift_number = ShiftCombo.Selected.Value
        ),
        "ID","Created"
    )
);

Self.Text = CountRows(Filter(colContextShift, IsToday(Created))) >= 1,
```